# is there a way to get array of values from form

Tags: javascript, angular8

angular 8 is used here

I need to get form data as an array.

These fields are generated according to api

is there a way to create a reactive form array group?

html

```
  <table
    *ngFor="let skill of assessment; index as i; let first = first"
    [ngClass]="{ active: first }"
    id="{{ i }}"
    class="table table-responsive table-condensed"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Assessment Zone</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Expert</td>
        <td>Apprentice</td>
        <td>Novice</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let skill_item of skill.skills; index as j" >
        <tr *ngFor="let set of skill_item.sets; index as k" >
          <td
            class="noborder middle"
            [rowSpan]="skill_item.sets.length"
            *ngIf="k == 0"
          >
            {{ skill_item.skill_name }}
          </td>
          <td class="middle">{{ k + 1 }}</td>
          <td>
            <p>{{ set.skill_items[0].desc }}</p>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="{{ k }}"
              value="{{ set.skill_items[0].id }}"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>{{ set.skill_items[1].desc }}</p>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="{{ k }}"
              value="{{ set.skill_items[1].id }}"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>{{ set.skill_items[2].desc }}</p>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="{{ k }}"
              value="{{ set.skill_items[2].id }}"
            />
          </td>
          <input type="hidden" name="skillItemId" value="{{skill_item.id}}" />
          <input type="hidden" name="skillGroupId" value="{{skill.id}}" />
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The data should be in this format

{
    "academicYearId":1,
        "term": "july",
    "studentid":999013909,
    "skills":[{

```
    "skillItemId":3,
    "skillId":1,
    "skillGroupId":1

},
{

    "skillItemId":2,
    "skillId":1,
    "skillGroupId":1

},
{

    "skillItemId":1,
    "skillId":1,
    "skillGroupId":1

}

]
```

}
[data from each field is taken as skillid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwaNk.png)

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried so far to achieve this.

Comment: You can use FormBuilder to make dynamic forms

Comment: FormBuilder seems to be the most suitable tool here.